# How To store State of Service fabric actor on Azure Blob,Azure DataLake or Azure

Tags: c#, azure, service, actor

I  have   requirement  to  store  state  of Service   fabric  Actor  out  of  Box  like on  azure  DocumentDb,Azure  DataLake ,Azure  SQL Server,SQL  Server  etc.

I  have  already   followed  the  Some  of   the   blog  to  byPass  State  of  Actor .  But   its  not   possible   to  USe,  out  of   box   functionality  as  storage,  so  that  when   Actor  Activate  i  will  get   Current   state   from  OutSide  Storage  and  when  Actor  de-activate    we  will  get   Actor  state  from  Storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can absolutely do it. You will loose replication though, since you are now responsible for persistence. Inside OnActivate you can rehydrate the state before any computation kicks in. Any change of the state you persist manually. We delegate this persistence to a diferent  actor types since the task in clearly relates to the infrastucfure.

Sergiy
<><